# Parsec: Consume all input

Tags: haskell, parsec

One common problem I have with Parsec is that it tends to ignore invalid input if it occurs in the "right" place.

As a concrete example, suppose we have `integer :: Parser Int`, and I write

```
expression = sepBy integer (char '+')
```

(Ignore whitespace issues for a moment.)

This correctly parses something like "123+456+789". However, if I feed it "123+456-789", it merrily ignores the illegal "-" character and the trailing part of the expression; I actually wanted an error message telling me about the invalid input, not just having it silently ignore that part.

I understand *why* this happens; what I'm not sure about is how to fix it. What is the general method for designing parsers that consume *all* supplied input and succeed only if *all* of it is a valid expression?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple--just ensure it's followed by `eof`:

```
parse (expression <* eof) "<interactive>" "123+456-789"
```

`eof` matches the end of the input, even if the input is just a string and not a file.

Obviously, this only makes sense at the top level of your parser.